# Как разделить ссылку по знаку вопроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получаю ссылки. Они могут быть разные, но нужно получать ту часть символов из ссылки, которая идет после знака вопроса. Пробовал убирать лишние символы до знака вопроса, но проблема в том что длина ссылки каждый раз разная...
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var link = "lalala?tatata"
var string = link.split("?")[1]; //tatata
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = window.location.search;
```

Если из текущего URL

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например еще, регуляркой:

```
var query = url.replace(/.*\?/, "");
```

Можно и циклом

```
var startQueryIndex = null;
var len = url.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(url[i] == "?") {
        startQueryIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
var query = url.substr(startQueryIndex); 
// вернет вместе с ?, если без него то (startQueryIndex + 1)
```

Comment: Регулярки для такой простой задачи - это как экскаватор для песочницы. К тому же, если ты знаешь о существовании split() и регулярок, должно быть стыдно предлагать использовать цикл

Comment: @P.Ilyin, можете заметить, что у меня самый последний ответ, поэтому он лишь дополняет предыдущие. А дублировать их код ни к чему